# Library for Abstractive Summarization

Tags: transformer, automatic-summarization

Is there a Python library that supports **abstractive** summarization? (Excluding cloud-based models like GPT or ChatGPT). We can perform **extractive** summarization easily using the code below:

```
!pip3 install transformers==4.11.3
!pip3 install summarizer
!pip3 install bert-extractive-summarizer
!pip3 install keybert
!pip3 install keybert[flair]
!pip3 install keybert[gensim]
!pip3 install keybert[spacy]
!pip3 install keybert[use]
!pip3 install spacy
!pip3 install "gensim==3.8.3"

from summarizer import Summarizer,TransformerSummarizer
GPT2_model = TransformerSummarizer(transformer_type="GPT2",transformer_model_key="gpt2-medium")
GPT2_summary = ''.join(GPT2_model(body, ratio=0.1))
print(GPT2_summary)
```

Answer (score 0):

HuggingFace T5 can perform abstractive summarization. There's a really good tutorial here: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tasks/summarization which includes finetuning, but this is optional.